# Can not apply z-index on autocomplete field

Tags: html, css, autocomplete

On my site I have a map "Leaflet" and in the menu of droute I have a field of research "Adessse". When I enter the first letter of a city in the address field, it displays a list of sugestion. My problem is that this list appears on the menu.

My menu has a z-index of 1028, I want to keep it.

How to apply a z-index of 1029 on the autocomplete field ?

[image]

**I solved the problem with :**

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    z-index: 1029 !important;
}
```

Now it works, but the list goes out of the window. I want her to stay in the menu :

[image]

On mobile it's a big problem :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can't you just do `.form-autocomplete { z-index: 1029; }` in the CSS?

Comment: @garrettlynch Yes thank you, I forgot !important

Comment: Ah so something is overriding it's z-index.  Be careful with `!important` it should really only be used when you know you are overriding a style and where that style is.

Comment: When I try that url: "La page demandée n'existe pas. Pour votre commodité, une recherche a été effectuée en utilisant les mots-clés : profile.".

Comment: @garrettlynch https://www.s1biose.com/profil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@3cfe5693 Ok I see what you mean now.  It's not a z-index issue.  I think you have a few issues that are combining.

Your .ui-menu-item class is actually a list and you have given it padding on the left and right.  Try setting these to 0px.  The box will also expand with the text inside it so give it a fixed width - whatever the width of the search box above it is.  Next you may need to add `word-wrap: break-word;` in the class to break very long words - it doesn't look like it will be needed as the box is wide enough to accommodate long words but its no harm to add it.

Read this page which explains word wrapping and how to accomplish it https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/

Comment: thank you, I have one last problem. When I scroll down the page, the sugestion list does not follow the address field.

Comment: That's to do with positioning in your CSS.  I can't see exactly whats going on as your classes are quite long and you are using a lot combined (you should simplify if you can) but the solution should be that the menu that opens from the right should be `position: fixed;` (as that doesn't move on the screen) and then the address box inside of that can be positioned by either using `position: relative;` or `position: absolute;` along with the required top/left/margins or padding to move it to its position under the search box.

Answer (score 2):

I guess problem here is that you are applying this z-index value to input field instead you have to apply this on the search results list which you want to display.
see here in my django code..

```html
{% for p in p1|slice:":7" %}
<li style="font-size:20px;z-index:4;" class="list-group-item"><a href="/products/product_info/{{p.id}}/">{{p.productname}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

i have a for loop to show the list of search results. Each result is shown under this list tag which has z-index high compare to other. you could also checkout my [website link](http://kunal8195.pythonanywhere.com/) to see it's working, search there something in the search bar.

Comment: The z-index works, the problem is that the list goes out of the window.

Comment: then you could make use of css align properties. class or id {
    text-align: justify; 
    -moz-text-align-last: right; /* Code for Firefox */
    text-align-last: right;
}

Comment: Where should the style be applied? on ".ui-autocomplete"? or on the menu

Comment: Try on both one by one and see which way it works for you.

Comment: I found with code(.ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item {
    white-space: normal !important;
}) but the first search comes out of the window, the second works correctly. It's weird, why ?

Comment: It's good it works. How to apply the autocomplete style only to #navbar-collapse-second ?